# Why would a Select from Tabke1 where FIeldA not in (Select FieldA from Table2) fail if I manually confirm it should work?

Tags: mysql

I ran

```
Select Term from TableA where Term not in (Select Name from TableB)
```

successfully. Yet when I tried another table

```
Select Term from TableA where Term not in (Select Name from TableC)
```

It returns a NULL set. I manuallyt confirmed there are literaly 1000s of records in TableA not in TableB and that the fields are correct.

Is there some other consideration I am not taking into account/understanding about what seems to be a simply query?

Update: Interestingly enough this alternative query worked:

```
 Select Term from TableA where not exist (Select Name from TableB where TableA.Term=TableC.Name)
```

So while I solved the problem at hand I am still curious why the first query worked for both tables but only the second worked on TableC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple example, consider the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ID NOT IN (1, 2, NULL);
```

This is semantically equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ID <> 1 AND ID <> 2 AND ID <> NULL;
```

The issue is with the last predicate (`ID <> NULL`). Nothing can be equal to null (not even null) and nothing can be not equal to null. The predicate returns neither true nor false, it returns NULL.

e.g.

| ID | ID <> 1 | ID <> 2 | ID <> NULL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FALSE | TRUE | NULL |
| 2 | TRUE | FALSE | NULL |
| 3 | TRUE | TRUE | NULL |

Since you need 3 "TRUE"s to satisfy the `AND` condition, no rows are returned, since none resolve to true for all 3 predicates.

You can get your `NOT IN` to work by excluding nulls, e.g.

```
SELECT Term 
FROM TableA 
WHERE Term NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM TableC WHERE Name IS NOT NULL);
```

But for this reason, and the potential for name clashes I always use `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Awesome and well described answer. I realized in fact this was why some of my within table queries failed on e.g flag fields where I used '1' for Yes and eventually got I had to default to 0 not NULL. Didn't occur to me this was the case here so thank you.